# iOS 9 enterprise app verify failed

Tags: ios, ios9, enterprise, adhoc

Apple change the way enterprise app verified on iOS 9, but when I verify our app in "Settings - General - Profiles", I got this 
[image: Verify failed]

I've check the log:

```
Oct 15 21:32:21 Nix-iPhone online-auth-agent[216] <Error>: Caller does not have required entitlement 'com.apple.private.mis.trust.set'
Oct 15 21:32:21 Nix-iPhone online-auth-agent[216] <Error>:  SecTrustEvaluate  [leaf AnchorTrusted]
Oct 15 21:32:31 Nix-iPhone online-auth-agent[216] <Notice>: Server returned no data
Oct 15 21:32:31 Nix-iPhone online-auth-agent[216] <Notice>: Could not complete online authentication
Oct 15 21:32:31 Nix-iPhone online-auth-agent[216] <Warning>: session error: The request timed out.
Oct 15 21:32:31 Nix-iPhone Preferences[223] <Warning>: Failed to verify provisioning profile d43b2b57-8def-4c46-88c9-fc57503890ad with error 32
Oct 15 21:32:31 Nix-iPhone Preferences[223] <Error>:  SecTrustEvaluate  [leaf IssuerCommonName SubjectCommonName]
Oct 15 21:32:31 Nix-iPhone Preferences[223] <Notice>: Authorization is pending.
Oct 15 21:32:31 Nix-iPhone Preferences[223] <Error>:  SecTrustEvaluate  [leaf IssuerCommonName SubjectCommonName]
Oct 15 21:32:31 Nix-iPhone Preferences[223] <Notice>: Authorization is pending.
```

Dose anyone know the reason and how to fix this?

Also tried VPN cause I'm in China, but did not work...

Comment: Today we also got this error. Apple server sucks

Answer (score 8, accepted):

I found this link: https://support.apple.com/en-us/HT204460 at the bottom mentioned that it connects to this site https://ppq.apple.com but this site has an invalid certificate which makes the verifying of app fails.
I'll bet apple will fix this right away.

Comment: Thanks, it seems they've fixed it.

Answer (score 4):

We are experiencing the same issue. I believe it is due to the Apple verification server.
I guess the only thing we can do now, is to WAIT until they fix it.