# iOS9 - Can't Verify Any Apps

Tags: ios, iphone, xcode

I was in the middle of woking on a App in XCode 7 and was pushing it to my phone after making changes.  All of a sudden, i was getting a general "security" error.

The app had already been verified and the developer trusted.  The XCode console outsputs:

```
error: failed to launch '/private/var/mobile/Containers/Bundle/Application/C684E25D-F370-4DFC-B39F-C4508B653EA1/myapp.app' -- process launch failed: Security
```

If I go to System Preferences > Profile in my phone and try to verify it, it doesn't do anything and doesn't report any feedback.

I've tried deleting the app, restarting xcode, restarting my phone, etc..

And now, none of my apps will install on my phone for development -- note, I'm only talking about directly launching an app from Xcode to my phone.  I'm not using the App Store.

Comment: Has anyone reported this to Apple? It has been down for hours now.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

It seems the server Apple uses to verify apps is down again. This has happened before: [iOS 9 enterprise app verify failed](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/33152151/ios-9-enterprise-app-verify-failed)

All we can do for now is wait until they resolve the issue.

Comment: I've opened a ticket with Apple Developer Program Support.  They didn't realize there was a problem but are supposed to be looking into it.

Answer (score 3):

Having the same issue as you, hitting VERIFY does nothing except briefly change my email at the top to 'Verifying", and then changes back.  No feedback or notification.

My first thought would be as Dominic said is that the server on Apples side is down.  Not sure if that server is listed here:

<strike>https://developer.apple.com/system-status/</strike>

But they all seem to be operational, so I guess all we have to do is wait.

**Edit: As per Dominic's post, this is the proper site: [ppq.apple.com](http://ppq.apple.com), which is currently down.**

http://www.isitdownrightnow.com/ppq.apple.com.html

**For any future people with this error:**

If you are having trouble verifying apps on your device, check the above site, if it is down that is almost certainly the cause.

Comment: In the stackoverflow post i linked to there was mention of this site https://ppq.apple.com which seems down at the moment.

Comment: Ah, my mistake.  Thank you, will update my comment.